# How to get a portable Xarginan presentation as you can do with ioslides?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I am pretty new to Rmarkdown presentations. I liked ioslides but it was quite a fixed theme, and Xarignan seemed more easily configurable (the visual aspect).

With ioslides, you get an html file with ALL the content (css, images, etc.). With Xaringan, I cannot get the images to work (seems like I need them to be in a folder in the same folder as the html file). Also, I am not sure if the html files uses something from the internet.

Comment: `xaringan`'s author Yihui Xie recommends against doing that:  https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/91#issuecomment-347885597

Comment: I'll work harder on `self_contained = TRUE` this year: https://yihui.name/en/2019/01/rstudio-conf/#jared-lander-s-annual-feature-requests :)

Comment: Thank you for your awesome software @YihuiXie. It would be great to get `self_contained = TRUE` to properly work, because sometimes in a congress there could be trouble with internet connection or something. You never know and you have to be prepared! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This problem](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/3) has been largely resolved. For now, you may try the development version of **xaringan**:

```r
remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan')
```

Images in slides should be correctly embedded now if you specify the option `self_contained: true` under the output format `xaringan::moon_reader`. The help page `?xaringan::moon_reader` has more information about the self-contained mode.